# Mongoengine connection timed out ReplicaSetNoPrimary

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

My project is running on docker and works perfectly fine on my machine. Once I upload it to the server (Ubuntu) and try the following:

```
print('a')
connect_db()
print('b')
record = Users.objects(id=ObjectId(userId)).first()
print('c')
```

It gets to b but stops working there. On line 4 it gives me the following error after some time:

```
bananadev-shard-00-02.u7tbh.mongodb.net:27017: timed out,bananadev-shard-00-00.u7tbh.mongodb.net:27017: timed
    out,bananadev-shard-00-01.u7tbh.mongodb.net:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description:
    &lt;TopologyDescription id: 61f261bc41e41fa3a3579d55, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers:
    [&lt;ServerDescription ('bananadev-shard-00-00.u7tbh.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
    error=NetworkTimeout('bananadev-shard-00-00.u7tbh.mongodb.net:27017: timed out')&gt;, &lt;ServerDescription
    ('bananadev-shard-00-01.u7tbh.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
    error=NetworkTimeout('bananadev-shard-00-01.u7tbh.mongodb.net:27017: timed out')&gt;, &lt;ServerDescription
    ('bananadev-shard-00-02.u7tbh.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
    error=NetworkTimeout('bananadev-shard-00-02.u7tbh.mongodb.net:27017: timed out')&gt;]&gt;
```

This is my mongodb connection string:

```
mongodb+srv://{user}:{password}@bananadev.u7tbh.mongodb.net/Banana_TEST?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Tried adding lots of different parameters at the end of my connection string like: ssl, directconnection, tlsAllowInvalidHostnames, …

I whitelisted the required ip's, created new users to connect from on mongodb.

Tried some different versions of mongoengine, adding a try-except inside my connect_db function but that part seems to work normally, ping & telnet on every shard from my server which worked without any issue as well.

I have been searching for a while, I hope someone knows the solution. Thanks.